# Graph QL request AWS Amplify

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, graphql, aws-amplify

I am trying to query Amplify to get data from a graphQl endpoint. I am sending the data to the backend successfully.
Below is the request from GraphQL

```
  const getFixtures = async () => {
    const clubProfile = await DataStore.query(ClubProfile, c => c.id(userUuid));
    setFixturesListData(clubProfile.fixtures);
    console.log('fixtures here', clubProfile);
  };
```

The output of the console is:
fixtures here [] (just an empty array)

The model is:

```
export declare class ClubProfile {
  readonly id: string;
  readonly club_email?: string | null;
  readonly club_name?: string | null;
  readonly club_number?: string | null;
  readonly club_description?: string | null;
  readonly club_website?: string | null;
  readonly club_teams?: string | null;
  readonly createdAt?: string | null;
  readonly updatedAt?: string | null;
  constructor(init: ModelInit<ClubProfile, ClubProfileMetaData>);
  static copyOf(source: ClubProfile, mutator: (draft: MutableModel<ClubProfile, ClubProfileMetaData>) => MutableModel<ClubProfile, ClubProfileMetaData> | void): ClubProfile;
}
```

I am trying different options and getting no success.

When I send the data to the backend:

```
    const clubInfo = async () => {
      let uuid = customerInfo.customerInfo.attributes.sub;
      const newClub = {
        id: uuid,
        club_name: clubName,
        club_email: clubEmail,
        club_number: clubPhone,
        club_location: clubLocation,
        club_website: 'https://www.clubWebsite.com',
        club_teams: {clubTeams},
        club_description: 'clubDescription',
      };
      await DataStore.save(new ClubProfile(newClub));
      console.log('newClub', newClub);
      setNewClub(newClub);
    };
    clubInfo();
  }
```

Comment: Are you using AWS AppSync - which is  a GraphQL solution?

Comment: What does the actual graphql query look like?

Comment: @Bergi It is in the question its the modal.... 2nd block of code

Comment: @smac2020 Yes I am

Comment: @JasonBeedle That's not GraphQL syntax. I mean the actual request that gets sent to the server.

Comment: @Bergi 
type Teams {
  Teams: String
}

type ClubProfile @ model @ auth(rules: [{allow: owner}, {allow: private}]) {
  id: ID!
  club_email: AWSEmail
  club_name: String
  club_number: String
  club_description: String
  club_website: AWSURL
  club_teams: AWSJSON
}

Comment: Ok that's the GraphQL schema you're using. Now what does the query look like that gives the unexpected results?

Comment: Btw where does `.fixtures` come from? I can't find that anywhere in the docs

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for the help I have solved it.. .I will add the answer...